# How to retrieve values of a function from a file

Tags: functions, function-construction, import, save

I defined the following function:

```
q5e8[z_?NumericQ] := q5e8[z?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[Sin[(2 5 10^8 - v) z]/z^5, 
  {v, 0.1, 2 5 10^8}]
```

As you can see, it is a function that remembers values it has found, so that i dont need to compute things twice. I saved the function to a file using

```
Save["q5e8", q5e8]
```

But now, how can I retrieve the definition and the values the function has evaluated from this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Get (<<)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html) to retrive the contents of the file `"q5e8"`:

> <<*name*
>   reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and returning the last one.

```
ClearAll[q5e8]
q5e8[z_?NumericQ] := q5e8[z] = NIntegrate[Sin[(2 5 10^8 - v) z]/z^5, {v, 0.1, 2 5 10^8}]
q5e8[1]
```

> 0.111805

```
Save["q5e8", q5e8]
```

After using `ClearAll[q5e8]` or in a new front-end session, using

```
Get["q5e8"]
```

loads the content of the file `"q5e8"`.

[image]